# Kafka connect can't find my custom write strategy

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to implement a custom write strategy for a sink connector that writes to mongodb as per the documentation here:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/fundamentals/write-strategies/

I am trying to get my connector to recognize the following (dummy) custom connector as a proof-of-concept:

```
package com.fu.connect.sink;

import org.bson.*;

import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOneModel;
import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions;
import com.mongodb.client.model.WriteModel;
import com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkDocument;
import com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.WriteModelStrategy;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException;

public class CustomWriteModelStrategy implements WriteModelStrategy {

    private static final UpdateOptions UPDATE_OPTIONS = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

    //incoming json should have one message key e.g. { "message": "Hello World"}
    @Override
    public WriteModel<BsonDocument> createWriteModel(SinkDocument document) {
        
        // Retrieve the value part of the SinkDocument
        BsonDocument vd = document.getValueDoc().orElseThrow(
                () -> new DataException("Error: cannot build the WriteModel since the value document was missing unexpectedly"));

        // extract message from incoming document
        BsonString message = new BsonString("");
        if (vd.containsKey("message")) {
            message = vd.get("message").asString();
        }

        // Define the filter part of the update statement
        BsonDocument filters = new BsonDocument("counter", new BsonDocument("$lt", new BsonInt32(10)));

        // Define the update part of the update statement
        BsonDocument updateStatement = new BsonDocument();
        updateStatement.append("$inc", new BsonDocument("counter", new BsonInt32(1)));
        updateStatement.append("$push", new BsonDocument("messages", new BsonDocument("message", message)));

        // Return the full update å
        return new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(
                filters,
                updateStatement,
                UPDATE_OPTIONS
        );
    }
}
```

(borrowed from https://github.com/felixreichenbach/kafkaWriteStrategy/blob/master/src/main/java/de/demo/kafka/CustomWriteModelStrategy.java)
I am compiling this class and some other custom transforms to a .jar and adding it to my plugin path using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY resources/custom_plugins /app/resources/custom_plugins
COPY resources/whitelist.csv /app/config/

WORKDIR /app/resources/custom_plugins
RUN mvn -e clean package

FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.2.2

ARG version
ENV VERSION=$version

USER appuser
RUN mkdir -p app/bin && \
    mkdir -p app/config
COPY --chown=appuser resources/truststore.jks app/config/
COPY --chown=appuser resources/whitelist.csv /app/config/

USER root

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter:5.5.3 && \
    confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.8.0 && \
    mkdir /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins && \
    mkdir /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins && \
    cp /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb/lib/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins && \
    cp /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter/lib/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins && \
    cp /usr/share/filestream-connectors/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins

USER appuser

ENV ARTIFACT_ID=CustomPlugins-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY --from=build /app/resources/custom_plugins/target/$ARTIFACT_ID /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins/$ARTIFACT_ID

COPY --chown=appuser scripts/*.sh app/bin/
COPY --chown=appuser config/* app/config/
```

my current plugin path:

```
plugin.path=/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins/CustomPlugins-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins/mongo-kafka-connect-1.8.0-confluent.jar,
```

in my sink properties I set

```
writemodel.strategy=com.fu.connect.sink.CustomWriteModelStrategy
```

I have tried a variety of different path configurations, including but not limited to adding all .jars to the same directory and only specifying one plugin path, and creating separate .jars for the SMTs and the custom write strategy. When I try to run my connector I always get the same error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Invalid value com.fu.connect.sink.CustomWriteModelStrategy for configuration writemodel.strategy: Class not found: com.fu.connect.sink.CustomWriteModelStrategy
```

my custom transformations work fine, but as far as I can tell the module that loads these transforms is different from the one that loads custom write strategies.

I have tried restructuring the Java code and the plugin path in all the permutations I can come up with, and I always get the same error

Answer (score 1):

figured it out: the problem was due to all the .jar file copying that happened here:

```
mkdir /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins && \
mkdir /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins && \
cp /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb/lib/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/mongo_plugins && \
cp /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-avro-converter/lib/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins && \
cp /usr/share/filestream-connectors/*.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/plugins
```

the plugin manager is very finicky about where the .jars are located when it comes to custom write strategies. simply removing all these lines and appropriately updating the plugin path fixed the problem

Comment: No, it isn't finicky. You define `plugin.path` or `CLASSPATH` on your own. You don't need to `cp` files around needlessly. A write strategy simply isn't something the Connect framework considers a "plugin"